# How to properly mention that a line of business with a different name is licensed under a company?

Tags: usage, terminology

Let's say **B** services is a line of business which is licensed under **A** company.

When promoting **B** services, how to properly mention that it is licensed under **A** Company (with very small font size)?

Comment: In UK the phrase ["A trading as B"](https://www.thecompanywarehouse.co.uk/blog/trading-as-company-and-business-names) can often be seen.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I would read that as being that B-Company is an alternate name for A-Company for the purposes of B-Service - what in the USA would be called a "DBA" - "Doing Business As". The question, as cast, does not imply any particular relationship between the companies, other than that the offeror of B-Service has licensed the service from A-Company.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I see, then perhaps company A's licence conditions stipulate how company B must state that fact.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Entirely possible, and would be relevant to the question, but the current casting of the question does not imply that there is any such requirement _in this case_. Naturally, if there _is_ such a stipulation, it must be followed, and makes the question as written irrelevant.

Comment: B have only business license. A have company license. The purpose of adding A-Company is to get more customer  trust for the B-Business.

Answer (score 2):

I usually see things like this as small-type footnotes "B-service is offered under license from A-company". Sometimes, there might also be a similar statement of the relationship between A-Company and B-Company "B-Company is affiliated with/an affiliate of/a [wholly-owned] subsidiary of A-Company".